# How to add Bearer token to a request in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, bearer-token

I have an API secured by Bearer token to be consumed in a mvc project. I'm using `ClientFactory` to call the API in mvc. I get the generated token from `WeatherForecast` `[HttpGet]` method and use it to to access the Authorized `PlayerController` methods. It works fine in Postman, But when I try to access `PlayerController` in mvc, On running a debugger It shows Unauthorized response!

Here is the action to get and use the generated token in mvc project

```
        private async Task<JWTToken> CreateToken()
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:42045/weatherforecast");
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            var token = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("JwToken", token);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JWTToken>(token);

        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllPlayers()
        {
            JWTToken token = null;
            var strToken = HttpContext.Session.GetString("JwToken");
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strToken))
            {
                token = await CreateToken();
            }
            else
            {
                token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JWTToken>(strToken);
            }
            if (token == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token.token) || token.expireAt <= DateTime.UtcNow)
            {
                token = await CreateToken();
            }
            List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:42045/api/player");
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.token);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var apiString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                players = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Player>>(apiString);

            }
            return View(players);
        }
```

Here is `CreateToken` method in `WeatherForecast` controller

```
[HttpGet]
    

public ActionResult<string> Get()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        var weathers = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        });
        return Ok(new {
            expireAt = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15), token = CreateToken()
        });
    }
    public string CreateToken()
    {
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configuration
            .GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));
        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            claims: new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim("firstName", "Ahmad"),
                new Claim("lastName", "Zooghii")
            },
            signingCredentials: creds,
            expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15)
            );
        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }
```

Comment: You could use Fiddler to see the HTTP request details and compare them to what works in Postman if simply debugging doesn't make it obvious. There are implementation details in your code that would be necessary to know in order to answer the question. My guess is you are handling the token wrong and sending an incorrect value.

Comment: @Crowcoder I just edited the post and added the method for creating token. I was wondering if there is any problem with this method

Comment: Can you show at which point you know it goes bad in your code? For example, are you getting a *valid* token in your response? What is the token value before you make the api request; is it what you expect and valid? At the very least I would read/log the response content even if it's unsuccessful. Also, adding `IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true; ` to the api might provide some more details.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Yeah it's valid. On running a debugger, the token value in mvc is correct. I used that token to access player controller in Postman and it worked! I put a break point just before if statement and on HttpResponseMessage and the header value in request is as expected

Comment: Did you mean that you used the token generated by your app to call the api via postman worked well? So you think the issue should be the code you used to call the api?

Comment: @TinyWang On running a debugger, I used the generated token to access the Authorized actions and it works fine in postman. The problem is with consuming the endpoint in my mvc project

Comment: So we can know the access token itself is correct right? Then the issue should come from the code you wrote to call the endpoint?

Comment: @TinyWang Yest the access token is correct because as I said I can access the Authorized controller on API in postman via that token

Comment: @TinyWang Can I have your email address so you may want to take a look at the whole solution in case you have free time?

Comment: I think you need to find the correct way to send Get request in asp.net core since your token is correct, so most of your code should be fine.

Comment: Could you pls check if you can send http request via your code or not? I assume that's the issue. By the way, does the url `http://localhost:42045/api/player` come from another project? If so, you may need to set Cors policy first.

Answer (score 1):

add `services.AddHttpClient();` in startup.cs

And this code in controller:

```
private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

public HomeController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
{
    _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
{
    var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    var token = "your_token";
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("your_url");
    return View();
}
```

[image]

======================Cors policy========================

add below code in startup.cs -> `ConfigureServices` method

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "mypolicy",
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin();
                      });
});
```

add `app.UseCors("mypolicy");` in startup.cs -> `Configure` method behind `app.UseRouting();` line.

Comment: both of the projects are in the same solution. Sorry bro how to set Cors? in Web API project or mvc or both?

Comment: Already done! I've done it before but I tried your sample code again and the response is the same! Unauthorized! I use that token in postman and it works fine! Wish I could send the whole solution to you, So you could take a look @TinyWang

Comment: In your api project, startup.cs file->Configure method, add `app.UseCookiePolicy();app.UseCors(builder =>builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());` to enable cors policy. And I do remembered some policy to get contact under the forum. Pls calm down sir, all the issues will be solved one day. And I recommend you that if enabled cors policy still doesn't work, you can create another controller in your MVC project and remove the authentication policy in your api project and call that api again with the new created controller, and if it worked, you switch to your own controller

Comment: Still failed! Here is the git address of my solution https://github.com/sia033007/MyWebAPIProject

Comment: You [didn't add cors policy](https://github.com/sia033007/MyWebAPIProject/blob/fcf2aa9916b1bfac53b291f867fda6c160ab8a68/MyWebAPIProject/Startup.cs#L33) here... Your request sent from the MVC project to the API project will fail.

Comment: Yeah it's not in the repository, But I tried it in my local machine and didn't work again!